# Unable to modify Views on MSSQL server

Tags: sql-server

I have recently had to take ownership of a MSSQL 2005 install.

There is only one database, with several tables and views, and I should have full permissions to everything, as far as I can tell. However, I am unable to `Modify` views (greyed out) or use `Script View as -> CREATE To -< ...` to copy a View (gives an error saying I don't have permission).

I notice that pre-existing Views have a little padlock icon on them, where as new one's I create do not. I have checked `Properties -> Permissions` and ensured that I have full permission of the view, which I do, so from here I'm a little lost.

Can someone please give me some pointers as to what I should be checking, to ensure permissions are set up correctly? Thanks.

Comment: Should you be a member of the sysadmin role on the server? Have you checked that you actually are? If you should only have permissions in that particular DB, then have you checked your database role membership?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am a member of `sysadmin`, by proxy of the `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` user. With regard to the database role membership, could you please explain in more detail how I check that?

Comment: When you run SQL Server Management Studio, you'll be connecting as *your* Windows user account, not the `SYSTEM` account. See Katherine's response.

Answer (score 1):

To make sure you're a member of the sysadmin group, use SQL Server Management Studio to go to Security -> Logins, and double-click your login (your actual Windows or SQL Server credentials, not NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM or your service account).  Make sure that the Server Roles tab lists you as a sysadmin, and, if not, make sure you have access to the database under User Mapping and are db_owner.

If you're not a sysadmin, your ability to access these areas may fail.  This article tells you how to get back in:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/937682